# XeLaTeX: ! Argument of \__sys_tmp:w has an extra } and other weird error messages

Tags: xetex

when I try to compile this mwe, XeLaTeX gives me a couple of weird error messages I don't understand. It still compiles a PDF for this MWE, but it has a "<" with whitespace at the beginning - in other files it gives the same error, but doesn't even create a PDF. Even with the MWE, it takes a *lot* of time to compile. I haven't used Latex in a bit, but before today eventhing was working, no idea what changed. I did all the reinstalling in an attempt to fix whatever was going wrong.

I'm using Texmaker 5.1.2 under Windows 10. I run XeLaTeX with the attributes: "xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex", configured in Texmaker config menu.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
Test
\end{document}
```

Stuff I already tried:

- completely deinstalled MiKTeX, reinstalled most recent version, run console, updated everything
- Installed most recent version of TexMaker
- MiKTeX is set to one user. (was even set to this before
- Updated Biber to the most recent version (I don't know if this has any relation to the error), I switched back to the older version, still same error.

````
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 2.9.7440 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2022.1.24)  24 JAN 2022 12:16
entering extended mode
**./Test2.tex
(Test2.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>
(C:\Users\furex\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\furex\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex\base\size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count179
\c@section=\count180
\c@subsection=\count181
\c@subsubsection=\count182
\c@paragraph=\count183
\c@subparagraph=\count184
\c@figure=\count185
\c@table=\count186
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(C:\Users\furex\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex\l3backend\l3backend-xet
ex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2021-12-14 L3 backend support: XeTeX
 ()
! Argument of \__sys_tmp:w has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
\q_stop \__int_eval_end: 
! Paragraph ended before \__sys_tmp:w was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \scan_stop: 
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_par:D 
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tex_par:D 
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

! You can't use `\numexpr' in horizontal mode.
\int_compare:nNnTF ...nt_eval:w #1#2\__int_eval:w 
                                                  #3\__int_eval_end: \__prg_...
l.80 ...c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int { 0 } }
                                                  
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

Missing character: There is no ^^@ in font [lmroman12-regular]:mapping=tex-text
;!
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count187
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count188
\g__graphics_track_int=\count189
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count190
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count191
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count192
) (Test2.aux)
\openout1 = `Test2.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 2
.

(C:\Users\furex\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex\base\ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.

[1

] (Test2.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 455 strings out of 413015
 9086 string characters out of 2858336
 309234 words of memory out of 3000000
 21058 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 403454 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 33i,5n,38p,146b,109s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on Test2.pdf (1 page).```

Thanks in advance!
````

Comment: hm, I can't reproduce it, but I don't have a 64bit miktex. Do you have a full miktex or did you install only the basic version? Also try to compile on a command line to avoid side effects from the editor.

Comment: I think the problem is that you don't have  `restricted \write18` enabled, and so  the backend can't get the dvipdfmx version but I need to test that.

Comment: What happen if you run on a command line `extractbb --version`  and `where extractbb`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is miktex really on `L3 programming layer <2021-11-22>` (not 2022-01-21 ?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes it lags behind currently. I had no updates for some weeks now.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but I think the problem is with extractbb, we had a similar error message there https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/850

Comment: Oh OK, but other than that it works for me even with `--no-shell-escape` (but different count numbers in the log)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer We use the 'get shell' code, so if there's no shell escape things should degrade gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for the input everybody! Sorry, this took so long, but full version of MiKTeX takes a *long* time to download and install. 

I had only the basic version installed so I tried to deinstall that and install the full version, but I got a "Ops, something went wrong" error message when deinstalling. The MiKTeX Error Report shows me:
"Windows API error 5: Zugriff verweigert" (=Access denied)
Details:
path="C:\Users\furex\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex/data/le\"

Comment: After that, in the windows cmd, it shows more files which are denied, but they are only there for sec and the window just loses. No idea where the log of this is.

I emptied the folder "C:\Users\furex\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX" by hand (because otherwise the installer won't let me install it, as the folder is not empty) and proceeded to install the full version.

Comment: After that, Texmaker drops me a short error msg: "Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed." for a sec, then XeLaTeX continues without error messages but generates no PDF. 

I even tried to install on another (not C:) drive, to another path, which isn't affected by Windows weird rights management stuff, but I got the same error/problem. Again, like mentioned earlier, I installed MiKTeX it just for one user, as this was the recommendation.

Comment: The cmd-line input "extractbb --version" gives me "This extractbb Version 20200315", "where extractbb" gives me 

C:\Program Files\Tools\Latex\miktex\bin\x64\extractbb.exe
C:\Users\furex\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\extractbb.exe

Comment: Okay, update: This might be an Texmaker issue after all. My file compiles fine with TeXworks now, but still doesn't work with Texmaker

Comment: you seem to have two miktex installed, one in ` C:\Program Files\Tools\Latex` and one in `C:\Users\furex\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX`. That is a receipt for confusion ...

Comment: @JosephWright yes I know  and it works fine for me if I disable shell-escape, but imho a missing or broken extractbb could be a problem.

Comment: Is there an easy way to deinstall one miktex to have only one? Windows deinstaller shows just one and this is C:\Users\furex\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX ; I'm pretty sure. Also suspecting TexMaker to use the other installation path. I try to copy all the data from one dir to the other, but this oviously is a very bad solution. I just want to check if stuff compiles now in TexMaker.

Comment: Okay, again an update: Copying all the files didn't work. I can still run everything in TeXworks, but TexMaker refuses to work. :(

Comment: sorry but it is not a good idea to click too fast on install/deinstall and similar buttons. And it is not a good idea to copy application files manually around, miktex (and windows) then will no longer be able to correctly manage your packages and updates. You only mess up your system if you don't think first a bit.

Comment: Situation is now how it is, however. I just wanted to test out if that changed anything, as the install-location was already there, I don't think this had anything to do with me clicking buttons too fast. Anyway, I was able to solve the issue: Manually deleting the first path solved the issue, everything compiles now fine in TexMaker. Still I know this isn't the way to go, so if there is a way to cleanly uninstall the second installation path, I will gladly take it. If not, at least everything is back to normal for now, eventhough updating something will prob. return to nightmare.